# How do I get the amount of free disk space in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova

I would like to store a significant amount of data on a device's nonvolatile storage in PhoneGap. How do I get the amount of available space so I can warn the user if there is not enough?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asking for the total available space, you can pass the amount of space you need as the second argument to `window.requestFileSystem (unsigned short type, unsigned long long size, FileSystemCallback successCallback, optional ErrorCallback errorCallback);`. This may be more useful anyway, as the user agent may have per-application storage quotas or be able to present a permissions dialog "May this application use 10 megabytes of storage?".